# Problems connection to SQL Server from Excel in VBA

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to be able to connect to a SQL Server from Excel using a Username/Password.  I have specified:

```
'Declare variables'
    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

'Open Connection'
    objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Driver=SQL Server;Server=SERVER\SERVER;Database=we_ci_db; Uid = genericReadWrite; Pwd=XYZ;"
    objMyConn.Open

'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
    strSQL = "select TOP 1 * from tblUsers WHERE alias='" & "username" & "'"

    'Debug.Print strSQL
'Open Recordset'
    Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
    objMyRecordset.Open strSQL

'Copy Data to Excel'
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
```

The code copies some basic details to a 'system' tab, updates some flags "UserID, SystemAccess" etc, before removing the password hash for security.

Now I thought it had been working fine up to now, but it had apparently been falling back to Windows Authentication (My team and I are explicitly listed as users on the SQL Server.

But when I get someone who isn't explicitly added as a NT Login to the server, it won't work.  Note the server IS set up for mixed authentication.

In Excel, we get `-2147467259 - [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open database "we_ci_db" requested by the login.  The login failed.`

The Server Logs say:
`Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\user'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: xx.xx.xx.xx]`

I would appreciate any assistance in getting this to work as it's starting to bug me.  I don't know if it's a SQL Server issue or a connection string issue, though the connection string at least partially works, even if the server is ignoring the username.

Comment: Has user, who is trying to login, got privilege to use "we_ci_db" database?

Comment: genericReadWrite has access as an SQL User (via User Mapping), the person is not listed as an NT User on the server/db.